# code or javascript for browser compatibility

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

i am developing a **web application** in asp.net - c#....

If i will define css classes like:

```
.IEStyle{color:Red;}
.FFStyle{color:Blue;}
.DefaultStyle{color:Black;}
```

i have tried it for only label....

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSample" runat="server" ie:CssClass="IEStyle"  
mozilla:CssClass="FFStyle" CssClass="DefaultStyle" ie:Text="You are in Internet  
explorer." mozilla:Text="You are in Firefox." Text="You are in other browser." />
```

it is good but its not possible for all time...still i'm facing problems with browsers compatibility....any one suggest me for that **i'm looking for javascript**. Giving with example is becomes easy for me to undderstand and integrate in my application...

Comment: I would question why you need to have a browser specific theme. It's not going to be easy for you to maintain and test...

Comment: I question why they want browser-specific *text*, too...

Comment: Trying to detect specific browsers is almost always the wrong approach … but you haven't told us what problem you think browser detection will help you solve, so we can't suggest a better one.

Comment: he's just testing out the code..  :p

Comment: i just giving an example,, i'm looking for best way to solve it.....

Answer (score 1):

This is not a common approach. However, consider having **separate stylesheets for each browser type**. The names of the rules (class names) would be the same in each stylesheet. Then, only load the stylesheet that you want.

Here is one way to dynamically load the stylesheet ([discussion here](http://voices.yahoo.com/loading-css-stylesheets-dynamically-browser-evalution-2161285.html)).

```
<link id="myLinkstyle" runat="server" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;

if (browser.Browser.ToLower() == "ie")

myLinkstyle.Href = "CSS/IEStyles.css";

else

myLinkstyle.Href = "CSS/OtherBrowserStyle.css";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the css :

```
/*default*/
label{color : #000;}
/*ie*/
.ie label{color : #ff0000;}
/*ff*/
.firefox label{color : #0000ff;}
```

And here's the js part :

```
if(navigator.userAgent.test(/firefox/i))
    document.body.className += ' ff';
else if(navigator.userAgent.test(/msie/i))
    document.body.className += ' ie';
// else => default
```

Here's what happens :  the javascript detects the browser name and sets a class name on to the body element. Your css rules react to that class name and color the labels differently for each browser.

Comment: what do you mean by "other way"?By the same logic, you could load different stylesheets as @DOK said, but if you want different styles based on different browser modes, you will do browser sniffing even if it's done server-side or client-side. Tell me what's not working for you.

Comment: when i'm developing a website it works fine in Mozilla FF but when loads in Another browsers like chrome, IE...it looks totally different for example asp web controls like button, dropdownlist etc...**I used a free templates for layouts** so what can i do for that...i'm 1'st time to develop any website...so plz help me